# Use program stack in a DFS implementation

Tags: c, stack

I have a standard DFS implementation in my code that uses a dynamically allocated stack on each call.

I call that function a lot. Often on just small runs (200-1000) nodes, but on occasion there is a large connected component with a million nodes or more.

A profiler shows that a significant amount of computing time is wasted on allocating the stack. I want to try to reuse existing memory (e.g. the call stack). However the function has to remain thread-safe.

Is there an efficient way to use the call stack dynamically without making the function recursive?

My best idea so far was to make the function recursive with an extra argument that doubles the automatic stack size on each subsequent invocation.

Pseudo C:

```
void dfs(size_t stack_length, void * graph, graphnode_t start_node) {
    graphnode_t stack[stack_length];
    size_t stack_size = 0;

    for (all nodes) {
        // do something useful
        if (stack_size < stack_length) {
            stack[stack_size++] = new_node;
        } else {
            dfs(stack_length * 2, graph, new_node);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're describing that your algorithm would work fine with just a single `graphnode_t` array for the system (though you're calling it a stack, I don't think that really applies here), and the only real problem is you're not certain how large it should be when you begin.

If that is the case, I would suggest first that you do not make this (potentially huge) array a local variable, because that will cause problems with your actual program stack. Instead let it be a static pointer that points to dynamically sized memory which you periodically expand if needed.

```
ensure_size(graphnode_t **not_a_stack_ptr, unsigned long *length_ptr)
{
    if (!*not_a_stack_ptr)
    {
        *not_a_stack_ptr = malloc(sizeof(graphnode_t) * MINIMUM_ENTRY_COUNT);
        *length_ptr = MINIMUM_ENTRY_COUNT;
    }
    else if (size needs to double)
    {
        *length_ptr *= 2;
        *not_a_stack_ptr = realloc(*not_a_stack_ptr, sizeof(graphnode_t) * (*length_ptr));
    }
}


struct thread_arguments {
    void * graph;
    graphnode_t start_node;
}

dfs_thread(void *void_thread_args)
{
    struct thread_arguments *thread_args = void_thread_args;
    graphnode_t *not_a_stack = NULL;
    unsigned long not_a_stack_length = 0;

    for (all nodes)
    {
        ensure_size(&not_a_stack, &not_a_stack_length);
        stack[stack_size++] = new_node;
    }

    if (not_a_stack) free(not_a_stack);
}
```

Note: your pseudo-code suggests that the maximum size could be determined based on the number of nodes you have. You would get the most performance gain by using this to perform just a single full-sized malloc up front.

Comment: I have thought of a global static variable. But that is where I get conflicts with thread safety. Each thread has to run it's own independent dfs with it's own private stack of nodes to work. The code has to be reentrant. I have considered making a stack per thread, but then I'd have to get rid of it when threads die.

Comment: Making a separate private array per thread is pretty easy to do, and getting rid of it on thread termination is also very easy. If `dfs` is non-recursive and able to stand as "the" thread, you would allocate the initial array up front as a local pointer/size, change the reallocation function to take the addresses of these, and clean up at the end of the function. (I'll update my answer to reflect this.) Is there something that makes you resistant to that possibility?

Comment: Note -- you didn't mention what kind of threading you're using. I've changed the `dfs` function to look like it _is_ the thread and, as many thread packages work, receives only a single `void *` argument -- so I've created a structure to point to for your real arguments.